# syntaxerror: unexpected token < in json at position 0 OpenCart 1.5.6

Tags: php, javascript, json, opencart

Помогите разобраться... Ничего в коде не менял, но внезапно при добавлении картинки к товару вылетает вот такая ошибка. Кстати такая же ошибка вылетает при входе в настройки сайта. syntaxerror: unexpected token < in json at position 0[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: json невалидный, т.к. начинается на `<!--...`

Comment: Не подскажите как исправить и где его искать? Я от js очень далек

Comment: ну, я тем более не знаю что там у вас :)  посмотрите через инспектор браузера запрос, убедитесь что `<!--...` пришло именно с сервера, после на сервере нужно будет найти место откуда было это отправлено. Еще можно в js обрезать строку с `<!--...`, тогда json должен стать валидным, но это просто костыль

Comment: http://prntscr.com/k3bhny    http://prntscr.com/k3bi0a    Вот что выдает инспектор, подскажите как мне найти место на сервере откуда это было отправлено?

Comment: Я так понимаю этот кусок кода отвечает за добавление изображений к товарам http://prntscr.com/k3bki8

Comment: похоже, это место формирования той страницы, а сама обработка запроса по `.../filemanager/files` находится в другом месте

Comment: А вот код из .tpl   http://prntscr.com/k3bm12

Comment: Я разобрался.... У меня в конфиге админа в конце файла была эта строка <!--user4117-->

Comment: Молодец, что сами разоьрались :)

Answer (score 1):

Я разобрался.... У меня в конфиге админа в конце файла была эта строка  –